# SearchBar hides under NavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I added a searchBar into a tableview. I also have a navigationbar and it should appear under it. It works fine until I tap into the searchbar. When I do so on devices with larger screen size (from iPhone 6) the searchbar hides under the navigationbar. It works as expected on an actual iPhone 5, 5s. This is how I initialize the searchBar:

```
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as UISearchResultsUpdating
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black


    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Device", "Person", "OS version"]
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self as UISearchBarDelegate
```

[image: Before I tap the searchBar]

[image: After I tapped the searchBar]

The searchBar should not hide because I need the segmented control on the navigationBar when I'm searching too. Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem?

**Update:** 
After setting the extended edges the searchBar looks like this:
[image: The navigationbar color changed]

[image: When I tap the searchbar]

Comment: Did you put any constraints to searchbar most importantly the top constraint.

Comment: No I did not set any constraints for that.

Comment: Probably this is the problem `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`, it should be hidden when the searchbar become active

Comment: try using some top constraint. the table view is fixed and i guess the search bar is linked to top margin of the tableview. Due to which on increase of height of the searchbar it went upwards.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem. It was an iOS 11 issue. According to wwdc recommendation you should add the searchBar for the navigationItem.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

} else {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

This solves the problem and it's working fine with any iOS type now. 
The searchBar will look like this on iOS 11:
[image: SearchBar with iOS 11]

Answer (score 0):

Select your viewController. Then in Utility Window you un tick the 
1:- Under Top Bars

[image: Like in this Image]

Comment: Yes that makes it work. Now the first row from the tableView gets hided under the scope buttons. And it also changes the navigationbar's color.

Comment: Sure, I updated the post. You can see it after the 'update'.

Comment: Ok Now you have to update your constraint. Please check the storyboard.